# SwiftUI: How to add a gray line bar on Sheet?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-sheet

I know how to add this element with `HStack` and `Rectangle`. But...

1. How is it called?
2. Does SwiftUI have this element out of the box?

[image: Unknown element]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037459/is-the-ios-grabber-drag-handle-a-uikit-component

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there's one accepted name for it; I usually call it a drag handle as it's there to indicate a draggable area to users.

There is no built-in syntax to add one to a sheet. That's the benefit of SwiftUI – simple controls are easy to implement and customize.

For completeness, you can make one using something like the following:

```
VStack {
    Capsule()
        .fill(Color.secondary)
        .frame(width: 30, height: 3)
        .padding(10)

    // your sheet content here

    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: When I place a Navigationview under it, it does not look like in the image tho.

Comment: How do you make the background behind the drag bar transparent when used in a .sheet modal?

Answer (score 21):

iOS16:

It is added automatically if you have more than one detent, so for just one detent you will have to be explicit about the visibility:

```
yourContentView
    .presentationDetents([.medium])
    .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
```

Comment: Interestingly, the drag indicator is not displayed if there is a Form on the sheet.

Answer (score 13):

1. The thing is called a `Drag Indicator`.
2. With **iOS 16+** you can use [.presentationDragIndicator(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationdragindicator(_:)?language=_5) modifier to control its visibility.

Proposals have been made on how to emulate this drag indicator in earlier iOS versions.

As a small addition to the great answers of John M. and happymacaron, this comes even closer:

```
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
    // NavigationView
    Capsule()
        .fill(Color.secondary)
        .opacity(0.5)
        .frame(width: 35, height: 5)
        .padding(6)
}
```

Comment: great but in dark mode it should be a bit brighter than this. I moved the opacity logic into a var that computes based on colorScheme, approx 0.7 for dark mode

Answer (score 4):

To add to John M.'s wonderful answer, you can use a `ZStack` to place the Capsule on top of the `NavigationView`. Like this:

```swift
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
    // NavigationView
    Capsule()
        .fill(Color.secondary)
        .frame(width: 35, height: 5)
}
```

I experimented with the size and found `width: 35, height: 5` produces a shape that is close to the image.