# Is the iOS grabber drag handle a UIKit component?

Tags: ios, uikit, draggable, drag, drawer

Apple has begun using a pill-shaped "grabber" drag handle grip to represent [draggable drawers in Apple Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967555/how-can-i-mimic-the-bottom-sheet-from-the-maps-app), Find My, etc.

> A grabber is a visual affordance that indicates that a sheet is resizable. Showing a grabber may be useful when it isn't apparent that a sheet can resize or when the sheet can't dismiss interactively.
>
> [UISheetPresentationController: prefersGrabberVisible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontroller/3801906-prefersgrabbervisible)

The drag handle is similar in design to the iPhone X home screen and app-switching icon released in iOS 11.

Are grabber handles a standard UIKit and/or SwiftUI visual component available in iOS and Interface Builder? I'm unable to find one within Xcode.

If there is not a standard component, how can such a grabber be built from UIViews?

---

[image: Apple Maps]

---

[image: Find My]

Comment: I think a common name is "bottom sheet" - There is no in-built component from Apple.  You can roll your own or there are some open-source implementations

Comment: I think [this package](https://github.com/mkko/DrawerView.git) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drag handle is a `UIGrabber` private class, not available in public UIKit:

> - https://twitter.com/rizwanasifahmed/status/1161221494166319104
> - https://twitter.com/harshil/status/1160172316287832064

It's not a public component available to use within UIKit. However, in iOS 15+, the new `UISheetPresentationController` has a `prefersGrabberVisible` property. Setting to `true` will at least display the system grabber within that sheet in your app.

Inspecting the item in Xcode's Debug View Hierarchy mode shows the private class name of `_UIGrabber`, as well as its properties:

[image: _UIGrabber in view hierarchy]